# My documents lost after migrating to new server

Tags: windows-sbs-2003

I lost the My Documents folder when migrating to a new server. Im using Microsoft Win Small business server 2003. How do I recover the lost 'My Documents' Folder.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply restore from your backup?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your old server or the hard drive, if you do and you have not securely deleted the data then try to use a recovery application like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).  *(suggested recuva as its a free app, but there are many more recovery applications in the market which are paid)*

Comment: The My Documents folder was being used offline for many months. By the time the user came back to work online we had migrated to a new server. When we configured and connected the laptop to the new domain, all changes made to files in My Documents folder when offline were lost.